# Getting NullPointerException in code which was working earlier

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a code to check PNR number. Because of internet issues, i thought to give users to check PNR by SMS. So I added 2 Radio Buttons, one for internet and one for SMS. But the problem is now when I click the PNR Button, it gives nullPointer Exception. 
Here is my Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private EditText pnrNumber;
    private TextView errMsg;
    private Button getPnr;
    private Button pnrClear;
    Button Yes, No;
    RadioButton checkbyinternet, checkbysms;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        errMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errMsg);
        pnrNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pnrNumber_p01);
        getPnr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkPNRButton);
        pnrClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pnrClear);

        getPnr.setOnClickListener(this);
        pnrClear.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View src) {
        // Perform action on click

        if (src.getId() == R.id.checkPNRButton) 
        {
            if (checkbyinternet.isChecked()) 
                {
                    int pnr2 = pnrNumber.getEditableText().length();
                    if (pnr2 != 10) 
                    {
                        errMsg.setText("Length of PNR is Invalid.");

                    } 
                    else 
                    {

                    String pnr = pnrNumber.getEditableText().toString();

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("pnr", pnr);

                    System.out.println("Connectivity : "
                            + this.isNetworkAvailable());

                    PNRStatus pnrStatus = null;
                    // Connect to the Server and Get the PNR status
                    try 
                        {

                            String captcha = "37819";
                            String pnr1 = pnrNumber.getText().toString();

                            String reqStr = "lccp_pnrno1=" + pnr1
                                    + "&lccp_cap_val=" + captcha
                                    + "&lccp_capinp_val=" + captcha
                                    + "&submitpnr=Get+Status";
                            PNRStatusCheck check = new PNRStatusCheck();
                            StringBuffer data = check
                                    .getPNRResponse(reqStr,
                                            "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnstat_cgi_28688.cgi");
                            // String pnr1 = pnr; //"1154177041";
                            // String reqStr = "lccp_pnrno1=" + pnr1 +
                            // "&submitpnr=Get+Status";
                            // PNRStatusCheck check = new PNRStatusCheck();
                            // StringBuffer data = check.getPNRResponse(reqStr,
                            // "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_pnrstat_cgi.cgi");
                            if (data != null) 
                                {
                                    pnrStatus = check.parseHtml(data);
                                    b.putSerializable("pnrStatus", pnrStatus);
                                } 
                            else 
                                {
                                // error
                                }
                        } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    Intent to = null;
                    if (pnrStatus != null) 
                        {
                            to = new Intent(this, PNRStatusActivity.class);
                            to.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(to);
                        } 
                    else 
                    {
                        errMsg.setText("Error prcessing PNR. Please try again.");
                    }
                }
            } 
            else if (checkbysms.isChecked()) 
            {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "SMS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int pnr2 = pnrNumber.getEditableText().length();
                if (pnr2 != 10) 
                    {
                        errMsg.setText("Length of PNR is Invalid.");

                    } 
                else 
                    {
                        openSMSWarningDialog(src);
                    }
            }

        } 
        else if (src.getId() == R.id.pnrClear) 
            {
                errMsg.setText("");
                pnrNumber.setText("");
            }
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // if no network is available networkInfo will be null, otherwise check
        // if we are connected
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void openSMSWarningDialog(View view) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.smsdialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Are you sure to use SMS.?");
        Yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        No = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.no);

        Yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String PnrNum = pnrNumber.getText().toString();
                String messageToSend = ("PNR " + PnrNum);
                String number = "139";
                SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null,
                        messageToSend, null, null);
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        "Please check your inbox in sometime for your PNR Status",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        No.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="10 Digits Mandatory" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pnrNumber_p01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextellipsedbackground"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:hint="@string/pnrTextView" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkPNRButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowRadius="5.9"
        android:text="@string/checkPNRButton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pnrClear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowRadius="5.9"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundlayoutborder"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/checkvia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/internet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="@string/CheckByInternet"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sms"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="@string/CheckBySMS"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

SMS Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9bafb0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:ems="27"
        android:text="@string/CheckThroughSMSWarning" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
            android:text="Yes" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bluebutton"
            android:text="No" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my LOG:

```
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at akshat.jaiswal.indianrailways.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-06 13:54:22.810: E/AndroidRuntime(858):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help, I am not able to get any solution for this.

Comment: On which line do you get the NPE? Also, if you recently edited your layouts, clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Post part of the stack trace and tell us which line it crashes on (and what line that is in your code, because we can't tell from the snippets you posted)

Comment: I think you are missing the initialization for checkbyinternet and checkbysms.

Comment: See now. Updated with log details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `checkbyinternet` and `checkbysms` buttons are uninitialized and that is why you're getting the `NullPointerException` when `if (checkbyinternet.isChecked())` is executed in the `onClick()` method.

```
if (src.getId() == R.id.checkPNRButton) // true if you pressed the getPnr button
        {
            if (checkbyinternet.isChecked()) // checkbyinternet is uninitialized yet, so it'll throw a NPE
```

You need to initialize them as well in the `onCreate()` method.

```
checkbyinternet = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.internet);
checkbysms = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sms);
```

Comment: Thats it. Sorry for such a silly question but did really not notice. Thank You. And why will I get NetworkOnMainThread exception.? And how to avoid it.?

Comment: @AkshatJaiswal - You may. I'm not really sure, but it seems you're doing network related stuffs in the main thread. You may need to move all the internet related code into an `AsyncTask` which is the default norm since Gingerbread. [Read more about it here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).